# Audio call error in quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox

i am facing this type of error.
plz help me.

```
  self.users = [ConnectionManager.instance usersWithIDS:self.session.opponents];
    //Start call
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"newcall" : @"newcall"};
    [self.session startCall:userInfo];
```

i m getting this error after startcall method.

[QBChat sendHeadlineMessageWithCustomParameters:toID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe322dbc350'

Comment: Is there code we can see?

Comment: i have demo. and i implement that in my code. there are lot of code so. demo is working perfect but i don't know what is messing. in my code.

Comment: Can you you add it to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problame is solve by this framework.

"QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.3.0.1";